# Is there a way to add prefixes to LESS file without compiling it into CSS?

Tags: webpack, less, autoprefixer

I tried [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) and [less-plugin-autoprefix](https://github.com/less/less-plugin-autoprefix), but it seems that both of them adding the prefixes after the conversion to CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `postcss-less` with `autoprefixer`

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
const syntax = require('postcss-less');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

gulp.task('default', () =>
  gulp.src('less/*.less')
  .pipe(postcss([
    autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] })
  ], { syntax }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('build/less'))
);
```